# Struggling with X11 raw raster

Tags: sockets, window, screen-scraping, x11, raster

[Preface: I have looked off and on for a direct-path for this for a years now.]

I get raw raster (1024x600, RGB/565) from a remote device. I want to display it in a simple X11 window. Because it represents a screen scrape, it needs to be fast/near realtime (30 fps min). I found a way to plug each pixel into a Pixmap/Bitmap, but there must be a way to hand the whole raster blob to Pixmap/Bitmap. Can anyone help? I just need a direct path:

data[] -> Pixmap -> paint into window.

```
uint8_t buffer[1024*600*2];
int byte_cnt = recv(client_sd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), MSG_WAITALL);
???; //--convert to Pixmap/Bitmap
???; //--paint in window
```

I cannot send a bitmap from the source, because I will run a simple RLE (run-length encoder) to speed data rates.

Thanks,

SW, PhM (PhD/ABD)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [XPutImage](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/XPutImage.html) to send whole 2d raster image to a drawable (Pixmap or Window) in one request. You'll have to decode rle on the client before sending ( and also probably convert from rgb 565 to format x server support)

If client and xserver are on the same physical machine (e.i share same memory) you can speed up this with MIT-SHM extension - see [XShmPutImage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/xshmputimage)